# Yosemite Can't start Xcode 6.1.1 with error -10699

Tags: macos, xcode

Recently i upgrade to Yosemite,

but i can't start my Xcode, when i try to start it via terminal using

```
open -a xcode
```

i got error:

```
failed for the application Xcode.app with error -10699
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Try running the Xcode binary directly instead of using LSS.

From the CLI:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
```

If something is wrong it will give you way more useful output.

Comment: `sudo open --new /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode` worked for me but now I have to use it all the time. This happened after applying Apple's system security update. Hoping that updating to Xcode 6.2 fixes it.

Comment: I have to say, using sudo is probably a rather bad idea. Xcode isn't a CLI application for one task, and everything it will do will be done as root. It's pretty much a symptom fix and not a problem fix this way.

The idea behind running it form a terminal window is that you might get more debug info on why LSServices is having trouble with your Xcode.

Comment: Xcode 6.2 did fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the latest version of Xcode installed? Error -106xx is in the range reserved for LaunchServices errors (although this particular error isn't listed in LSInfo.h). It may be telling you your copy of Xcode is too old to run under Yosemite. (The current version for Yosemite is 6.1.1.)